Chartjs Nextjs - Both the Two charts should display crosshair if hovered on any one
Two line charts should display crosshair if hovered on any one. When first chart is hovered crosshair is displayed on the first but on second chart only points are highlighted without the crosshair
import crosshairPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-crosshair';
Chart.register(...registerables, annotationPlugin, crosshairPlugin);

But when trying to add crosshair inside plugin variable in options it doesn't allow it
